# How to store objects in a array using javascript

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

i am developing extesnions for safari browswer. i want to store current active tab objects in a array as key. how to store multiple tab objects in a array.

i wrote following code.

**First scenario:

```
var obj = {};

obj1=new Object();
obj2=new Object();
obj3=new Object();

obj['cTab_'+obj1] = "This is object1";
obj['cTab_'+obj2] = "This is object2";
obj['cTab_'+obj3] = "This is object3";**
```

prblem is i am getting 3rd object value. how to get all the object values.

**Second scenario:

```
var arr = new Array();

cTabObj1 = new Object();
arr[cTabObj1] = 'This is cTabObj1 Value';

cTabObj2 = new Object();
arr[cTabObj2] = 'This is cTabObj2 Value';

cTabObj3 = new Object();
arr[cTabObj3] = 'This is cTabObj3 Value';

alert("arr[cTabObj1]    :" + arr[cTabObj1] + " arr[cTabObj2]    :" + arr[cTabObj2] + " arr[cTabObj3]    :" + arr[cTabObj3]);**
```

Here also i am getting **"This is cTabObj3 Value"** for all three object

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first problem is happening because the objects will all have the same string representation. However my initial suggestion would be your second scenario; since that doesn't work this becomes an interesting problem.

Comment: Duplicate question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896567/how-to-store-object-as-key-in-a-array-using-javascript/6896871#6896871

Answer (score 1):

> i want to store current active tab objects in a array as key

You can't do that. Keys are strings. They always are strings.

If you take a look at the array you will find any object gets converted to `"[object Object]"` so your basically inserting the same key 3 times.

Use `console.log(arr)` or `console.dir(arr)` together with firebug or chrome/opera/safari

What you want is a ES6 `WeakMap`.

Only Firefox6 implements [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896567/how-to-store-object-as-key-in-a-array-using-javascript/6896871#6896871

Comment: @Morre defining your own `toString` for objects is a clever trick. Didn't think of that

Comment: I ALWAYS do that (toString) for ALL objects anyway - very good for debugging, much better output in Firebug ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The keys need to be strings.

Try implementing the `toString` method on your objects so that it returns a unique identifier for each object. Then `'cTab_' + obj` will be a unique string.

Answer (score 0):

Your first scenario is the way to go except that you have assigned the same subscript key to each object that you are storing in `obj`. When you use anything other than a string for an object property key, the value has `toString()` called on it internally, so

```
obj['cTab_'+obj1] = "This is object1";
obj['cTab_'+obj2] = "This is object2";
obj['cTab_'+obj3] = "This is object3";
```

will all have the same key of `cTab_[object Object]`.

What you need is to differentiate the keys. Since each object will return "[object Object]" when `toString()` is called on it, you can remove the object from the property key too as it is redundant e.g.

```
var obj = {};
obj['cTab1'] = "This is object1";
obj['cTab2'] = "This is object2";
obj['cTab3'] = "This is object3";
```

or more tersely

```
var obj = {
    cTab1 : "This is object1",
    cTab2 : "This is object2",
    cTab3 : "This is object3"
};
```

The reason why the second way is **not** the way to go is that you are [trying to use a JavaScript array like an associative array](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), which they are not; it may seem to work at first but then you will discover some very odd behaviour, such as `arr.length` does not count them as items in the array, etc. For more details, read the linked article.  You want to use `Object` (`{}`) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather store like this

```
cTabObj1 = new Object();
arr["cTabObj1"] = cTabObj1;
```